# Is there any alternate way to but a click listner on a button in vaadin rather than using addClickListner()?

Tags: vaadin7

I have tried addClickListner()  method but this is a depricated one so its generating problem in its implementation.
So is there any way rather than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[addClickListener()](https://www.vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Button.html#addClickListener%28com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener%29) is **not** deprecated. Only [addListener()](https://www.vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Button.html#addListener%28com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener%29) is.

Comment: OK so what can i use in place of addListner() ?